# Python - setattr function without self parameter, 2 parameters instead of 3

Tags: python, django

I have the following code where I need to use setattr to generate the variable from the string and set it equal to `amn`.

```
for i in amenities:
    if i in request.GET:
        amn = request.GET.getlist(i)
        propertiesList = Property.objects.filter(setattr(i+"__title__in", amn))
```

It seems setattr takes 3 parameters, how can I do it with just these 2 parameters?

Comment: `setattr` sets an attribute of an object and returns `None`. What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not use `setattr` to achieve what you want, try this:

```
propertiesList = Property.objects.filter(**{i+"__title__in": amn})
```

Comment: when i is `"foo"`, it equals to `Property.objects.filter(foo__title__in=amn)`, search "python dict unpacking".